# Python regex from txt file

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file, that has data.

```
PAS_BEGIN_3600000
    CMD_VERS=2
    CMD_TRNS=O
    CMD_REINIT=
    CMD_OLIVIER=
```

I want to extract data from that file, where nothing is after the equal sign.

So in my new text file, I want to get

```
CMD_REINIT
CMD_OLIVIER
```

How do I do this?

---

My code is like that righr now.

```
import os, os.path

DIR_DAT = "dat"
DIR_OUTPUT = "output"

print("Psst go check in the ouptut folder ;)")
for roots, dir, files in os.walk(DIR_DAT):  
    for filename in files:
        filename_output = "/" + os.path.splitext(filename)[0]   
        with open(DIR_DAT + "/" + filename) as infile, open(DIR_OUTPUT + "/bonjour.txt", "w") as outfile:
            for line in infile:
                if not line.strip().split("=")[-1]:
                    outfile.write(line)
```

### I want to collect all data in a single file. It doesn't work. Can anyone help me ?

The third step, it do crawl that new file, and only keep single values. As four files are appended into a single one. Some data might be there four, three, two times.

And I need to keep in a new file, that I will call output.txt. Only the lines that are in common in all the files.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex:

```
import re

data = """PAS_BEGIN_3600000
    CMD_VERS=2
    CMD_TRNS=O
    CMD_REINIT=
    CMD_OLIVIER="""

found = re.findall(r"^\s+(.*)=\s*$",data,re.M)

print( found )
```

Output:

```
['CMD_REINIT', 'CMD_OLIVIER']
```

The expression looks for

```
^\s+  line start + whitespaces
(.*)=  anything before a =  which is caputred as group
\s*$   followed by optional whitespaces and line end
```

using the [re.M (multiline)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) flag.

Read your files text like so:

```
with open("yourfile.txt","r") as f:
    data = f.read()
```

Write your new file like so:

```
with open("newfile.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(''.join("\n",found))
```

You can use http://www.regex101.com to evaluate test-text vs regex-patterns, make sure to swith to its python mode.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you the following short solution using comprehension:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as newf:
    for x in (line.strip()[:-1] for line in f if line.strip().endswith("=")):
        newf.write(f'{x}\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this pattern: `\w+(?==$)`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DeqzVc/3)

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
with open(filename) as infile, open(filename2, "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:                          #Iterate Each line
        if not line.strip().split("=")[-1]:      #Check for second Val
            print(line.strip().strip("="))
            outfile.write(line)                  #Write to new file
```

**Output:**

```
CMD_REINIT
CMD_OLIVIER
```

Comment: It worked fine ! Just had to modify this part : open(filename2, "w"). Now it can write in filename2 txt file. Thanks :)